# Nginx configuration location and index

Tags: nginx

This is how my configuration looks like...

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name 127.0.0.1 localhost;

location = / {
  index index.html;
}

location / {
  root /etc/nginx/html/app1;
  }
}
```

In my folder app1 I have two files, index.html & home.html

If I browse http://localhost/ or http://localhost/index.html or http://localhost/home.html page it comes up well.

When I change the configuration like so...

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name 127.0.0.1 localhost;

location = / {
  index home.html;
}

location / {
  root /etc/nginx/html/app1;
  }
}
```

http://localhost:8888/index.html > works
http://localhost:8888/home.html > works
http://localhost:8888/ > 403 forbidden!!!

Can someone please tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the priority of `location = {}`  is higher `location / {}`.
So it first matches the `location = {}`.
In you case, there isn't **root** in the `location = {}`.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. A quick followup question... why do we need to define root at both locations, especially that I know that = / will eventually do an internal redirect?

Comment: @RahulSoni   You can define `root` in `server` section too not only in `location` sections.

Comment: Yeah, if this server is only one project, you can put the `root` in `server`.

Comment: Yes, that's the plan. This structure was just to simply my query. Thanks again!